# Add custom fields to Stripe Invoice PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments

```
\Stripe\Invoice::update($invoice_id, [
'custom_fields' => [
[
'name' => 'Company',
'value' => 'Apple'
]
]
]);
```

And I got error with custom_fields. I didn't find example in Stripe documentation how to use custom_fields, but in JSON it should be `custom_fields: [{name:'Company',value:'Apple'}]` but now it is `custom_fields: {0:{name:'Company',value:'Apple'}}`

EDIT:
[image]
I am trying to add `custom_fields` to invoice on subscription on `invoice.created` event.

```
case 'invoice.created':
    $invoice = $event->data->object;
    $invoice_id = $invoice->id;
    $updated_invoice = \Stripe\Invoice::update($invoice_id, [
                'custom_fields' => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'Company',
                        'value' => 'Apple'
                    ]
                ]
            ]);
```

Maybe in test mode it happens too quickly, and `invoice.created` quickly changes to `invoice.finalized`

Comment: Your syntax looks correct since custom_fields expects an array of hashes. What is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: I have added image.

Comment: Oh it's because you can't add custom fields to finalized invoices. You should do that when they're in a draft state.

Comment: Yes thanks, stripe support helped me with that, first invoice in subscription starts immediately and it is impossible to edit it.